# React not picking up on route changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

[image: HomePage.js]

[image: Main.js]

[image: Props]

I ran into a weird error while working on this project. My redux state has a route path that is set to '/news' and initialized on render and I do receive props at first but I don't when I switch routes by clicking on my Navigation Links and that is because my redux state isn't updating because I'm not receiving props. How can I fix this?.

Comment: It would be great if you could share code sandbox link